# Should I choose "new" or "newly"?

Tags: grammar

> Partitioning is typically the first step of preparing a ..... manufactured disk, before any files or directories have been created.

That blank need a adverb or adjective. There are two options :**new** or **newly**.
So which word is correct in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Use **newly**. This refers to the recency of the manufacturing of the disk.

If you use **new** you are refering to it as a *"manufactured disk"* as opposed to *"handcrafted disk"* or *"homemade disk"* or however else a disk might be produced/created.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **newly**, then it will mean a disk that has been recently produced, the emphasis being on the recency of production.
Meanwhile, as an adjective, **new** will place stress on both the fact that it is recently produced as well as the fact that it is "manufactured".

In other words, if you want to point to a recently made disk, use **newly**.
But if you also want to have manufactured as a stressed adjective, use **new**.
Hope that helps :)

Comment: **newly** is a adverb, and it modifies the adjective "manufactured".
**new** is a adjective, and it modifies noun. 
So, I don't understand why it can use **new**, and why **new** will place stress the fact that it is "manufactured". I think **newly** just will.

Comment: Manufactured as an adjective, is more emphasized as a means of production when there is no adverb referring to when the manufacturing took place. Newly as an adverb changes the meaning of manufactured, while the adjective new merely adds another trait to the noun, hence leaving the manufactured adjective unmodified and stressed.

Comment: I think using "new" in this case is not correct, because **new** is an adjective so it can't modify the other adjective(manufactured) .
Only **newly** can be used in this case , because it's a adverb and it modifies the adjective "manufactured".